# How to fix non-manifold boundaries

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, 3d-printing

I am new to 3d modeling, and I have some problems after finishing my project. To preface, my goal was to create a tiger mask.

My problem is that when I show my non-manifold elements, I have some non-contiguous and boundaries non-manifold, shown below:
[image]

[image]

As I said, I am new to 3d modeling, but I did notice that the boundaries ones were shown where there was a hole or opening, as in the eyes, mouth, or back. Why would this be? I could find nothing that would cause the non-contiguous ones as well.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry. Loops which are disconnected from other geometry even if have connections to parts of mesh (like those selected on your mesh) are also treated as non-manifold. If you add some thickness to your mask, the mesh will be treated as manifold. You can use **Solidify** modifier for that.

Comment: If the mesh is not closed, that is one type of non-manifold geometry. Adding a Solidify Modifier is one solution, if you're concerned about it. In real life too, a mask could not be infinitely thin.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have fixed my boundaries, but I still have quite a lot of non contiguous. What could these be caused by and should I worry about them?

Comment: I realize you have long since figured it out, but this is one of the top Google hits for when I was trying to find out.  Non-contiguous means that some of the normals are facing this way and some are facing that way.  Recalculate your normals, and if you have a good mesh, it should work itself out.